# How do I test with injected class? Junit return NPE

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a simple service like below

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   @Inject SomeClass someClass;

   public resp doSomething(){
     return someclass.executeSomething();
   }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
public class SomeServiceTest {
   @Mock
   SomeClass someClass;

   MyService myService;

   @Before
   public setUp() {
      myService = new MyService();
   }

   @Test
   public void testExecute() {
      Resp resp = myService.doSomething();
      assertNotNull(resp);
   }
}
```

I am getting nullpointer exception when pointed at `someclass.executeSomething(); where someclass is null`. How do I mock the injected class?

Comment: You use constructor injection, which is a best practice anyway.

Comment: Besides constructor injection you can also use Mockitos @InjectMocks Annotation. It will instanciate ur Service and Inject all the matching mocks into it

Comment: I never heard of it, do you have some examples? and I did tried @InjectMocks but it still throws null pointer when I run the test

Comment: It says Mocktio cannot spy/mock: final class

Comment: You have to initialize Mockito-Annotations. Either use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) or annotate ur Test-Class with @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)

Answer (score 2):

Like suggested in my previous comment, like this should do the trick.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
   @Mock
   SomeClass someClass;
   @InjectMocks
   MyService myService;
  
   @Test
   public void testExecute() {
      Resp resp = myService.doSomething();
      assertNotNull(resp);
   }
}
```